# Merging two JSON strings in Python, with value lists

Tags: python, json

I am looking to merge two JSON strings into one in Python.  string1 has identical Keys as string2, but string2 has several values in a list, like the example below:

string1:

```
{'Target': 'DEV1', 'Supplier': '0', 'Message': 'A', 'Name': 'Supp1'}
```

string2:

```
{'Target': ['DEV2', 'DEV3'], 'Supplier': ['1', '2'], 'Message': ['B', 'C'], 'Name': ['Supp2', 'Supp3']}
```

Hopeful Merged Output string3:

```
{'Target': ['DEV1', 'DEV2', 'DEV3'], 'Supplier': ['0', '1', '2'], 'Message': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'Name': ['Supp1', 'Supp2', 'Supp3']}
```

I'm not too familiar with JSON, but here's my current position:

```
import json

str1 = json.loads(string1)
str2 = json.loads(string2)

string3 = {key, val for (key, val) in (str1.items() and str2.items())
```

The last line I found in Stackoverflow for merging JSON strings, but I am struggling with the list appending for each value.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post `print` for the three strings?

Comment: The Json your provided is not in the same format, what if you have two string1 with different value on `Value`? What's supposed to be the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an easy way to achieve what you want.

```
merged_str = { key: [str1[key]]+str2[key] for key in str2 }
```

BTW they are called dictionaries and not JSON strings.

Comment: OP has specifically mentioned that string2 has the list.

Comment: Thanks, this method worked for me, and looked to be the simplest solution

Answer (score 1):

Now is an working answer

```
def toList(x):
    if isinstance(x, list):
        return x
    else:
        return [x,]  

s3 = {k:toList(s1[k])+ toList(s2[k]) for k in s1.keys()}
```

assuming same keys in both s1 and s2